# How to send parameters and upload file to one action

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Answer:
The problem seems to be with the definition of the form. instead of `asp-action` i changed it to `action` and changed the value to /MyController/ActionName/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3 and that did the trick. If anyone could explain why this works (even though VS says that this path is not found) i would love an answer. Thank you.

I am trying to upload a file and send few parameters to an action in my ASP.NET Core `Controller`. However the form submit button keeps redirecting me to the Index action and not what im specifying. I have tried googling this and didnt come up with an answer.

Note: im using Razor Views

My Controller (This is HomeController):

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("[controller]/[action]/cardNumber/sectionId/file")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GenerateSingleCardData(string cardNumber, int sectionId, IFormFile file)
    {
    .... UNREACHABLE CODE
    }
```

Snippet of my view (this is SingleCardForm partial view):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="GenerateSingleCardData">
Select file : <input type="file" name="file" required/> <br/>
Card Number: <input type="text" name="cardNumber" required/> <br/>
SectionID: <input type="number" name="sectionId" required/> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Start"/>
```

EDIT:
Full view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="/JQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>


<input type="radio" name="ActionType" checked="checked" onclick="ShowSingleCardForm()"> Single Card <br/>
<input type="radio" name="ActionType" onclick="ShowAllCardsForm()"> All Section Cards <br/>

<div id="Form">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("SingleCardForm")
</div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
    function ShowSingleCardForm() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetSingleCardForm", "Home")';
        LoadForm(url);
    }

    function ShowAllCardsForm() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetAllCardsForm", "Home")';
        LoadForm(url);
    }

    function LoadForm(url) {
        var formDiv = document.getElementById("Form");

        while (formDiv.firstChild) {
            formDiv.removeChild(formDiv.firstChild);
        }

        $('#Form').load(url);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The code you have shown will not redirect you to the `Index` action so its code you have not shown causing the issue. Check that you do not have nested forms

Comment: Added the entire Index.cshtml. Not sure what else theres to add.

Comment: Why do you have a `[Route]` attribute with parameters? - you are not generating route values - you are posting a form - that should be removed

Comment: but then how do i access the parameters?

Comment: Because you have the parameter in the signature of the method (they will be bound from the form values)

Answer (score 1):

1. When specifying route parameters, they must be enclosed by curly brackets, i.e. `[Route("[controller]/[action]/{cardNumber}/{sectionId}/{file}")]`, not `[Route("[controller]/[action]/cardNumber/sectionId/file")]`.
2. You can only use primitives (int, string, etc.) as route params. In other words `{file}` will not work, because it's of type `IFormFile`, and there's no way to bind that into the route.
3. The route is the URL for your action. As a result, all route params must be specified in order to generate the URL. That's not what you're doing here. You need a simple static URL, which you then are posting data to. In other words, change it to just `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]`. The data you're posting comes from the POST body of the request, and will be bound to the respective params of your action method.
4. While not a problem. per se, it's redundant to specify both `Route` and an HTTP verb attribute like `HttpPost`. Just do:

   ```
   [HttpPost("[controller]/[action]")]
   ```